# How to define what object is put in method from outside

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, object, methods

I was wondering how can i declare what object is going to be put in method from outside.
Of course when they cannot be passed to the method as parameters.

**what I mean :**

```
// Suppose we have these two objects/Classes
Object First;
Object Second;

// Now we need to define whether 'First' Or 'Second' is going to be used in bar()
// This Condition cannot be inside the bar() itself.
if (Condition) 
   // Use First in bar()
else
   // Use Second in bar()


void bar(){
  
     Console.Log(
         First 
         // OR (defined before)
         Second
     );
}
```

One way i thought of is to make a substitute object that points to the object i want to use. like if i change `Substitute` the `First` or `Second` changes based on the condition's result. but how can I do this?

**PS:** As for why do i want to do this instead of putting the if statement in the method itself, it's for better optimization, plus it's much neater this way, if any. If I make a third Object that stores the values well it's not going to change the primary objects' values. `(for example a transform.position)`

and in my particular case I need this for Unity `Update()` function. Since it will have to check the `if statement` every frame if it's inside, and it doesn't accept parameters.

So it will be much better if it's declared in let's say `Awake()` which one is going to be used in Update. Also if you have tips about this case i'll be glad to hear.

Comment: I asked this to get an answer on how to optimize use of a condition in unity. if it doesn't make sense i'll be glad to know why, not to get downvotes on it.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly what you want to achieve, use a property like this:

```
private Object First;
private Object Second;

public Object SelectedObject {
     get {
            if (Condition) 
                   return First;// Use First in bar()
            else
                   return Second;// Use Second in bar()
     }

     set {
           if (Condition) 
                   First = value;// Use First in bar()
            else
                   Second = value;// Use Second in bar()
      } 

} 


// Now we need to define whether 'First' Or 'Second' is going to be used in bar()



void bar(){
  
     Console.Log(
         this.SelectedObject
     );
}
```

Comment: but hey, i cannot assign to property, says it's read only. know how i can deal with that? since its literally what i need, i need to be able to change the primary objects' values.

Comment: If it's Object First then First Should change if Second then Second.

Comment: But the if else is still made every time you get the value, so that does not optimize anything, just moves the check to another place.

Comment: @Saplu you are right. well i think I haven't found a way to optimize it. I seriously wonder how others handle it. it's such a clear question I don't know why im getting downvotes! Supposing there are multiple if statements checking them every frame would take a big toll on performance.

Comment: If you need to decide something based on a condition, then you can only use if. In modern computers if the cars are not thousands, then the performance impact is negligible

Comment: I could change it to an array solution going a ++ operation if there are more than two, but either an if case or an addition would mean the same performance "hit".

Comment: Well if it doesn't need to be checked every frame and is only declared once. putting the if inside Update() makes no sense. I need to know whether Object first Or Object Second is going to be used, and that is declared upon the very start.

Comment: They alternate or is it decided in the constructor? If it's decided in the constructor, declare an array and set the index in the constructor, then access the array by the index.

Comment: em, well I can make an array of two objects but these objects are not the 'First" and 'Second'. can you clarify more or edit your answer if you think that's the way. and yes they can be defined in a constructor. (whether it's 'First' or 'Second' that's going to be used)

Comment: Or a `void Main()`, since it's pretty much the same as Unity's `Awake()`/`Start()`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220677/discussion-between-sorena-and-athanasios-kataras).

Comment: How about if you just set the value of either First or Second to SelectedObject in the setter based on the condition. Then you could just return SelectedObject and use that instead of First or Second.